# Gradle - generate single Visual Studio solution for multiple native components

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm porting large codebase from custom build system to Gradle.

Do I have any way to generate single VS solution with 2 projects instead of 2 separate solutions?

my example build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'cpp'
apply plugin: 'visual-studio'


model {
    components {
        debugger(NativeExecutableSpec) {
        }

        nativeagent(NativeLibrarySpec) {
        }
    }

    visualStudio {
            solutions.all {
                solutionFile.location = "vs/${name}.sln"
            }

            projects.all {
                projectFile.location = "vs/${name}.vcxproj"
                filtersFile.location = "vs/${name}.filters"
            }
    }
}
```

output from `.\gradlew tasks`:

```
.....
IDE tasks
---------
cleanVisualStudio - Removes all generated Visual Studio project and solution files
debuggerVisualStudio - Generates the Visual Studio solution for native executable 'debugger'.
nativeagentVisualStudio - Generates the Visual Studio solution for native library 'nativeagent'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself, Just specify dependencies between projects:

```
debugger(NativeExecutableSpec) {
            sources {
                cpp {
                    lib library: "nativeagent"                      
                    source {
                        srcDir "debugger/src"
                        include "**/*.cpp"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

and run `.\gradlew debuggerVisualStudio`